desaparece ventana de buscar en IDE eclipse
Al acceder a una clase java cualquiera en eclipse, si intento buscar (ctrl+f) aparece la ventana emergente donde realizar la búsqueda pero va desapareciendo y finalmente desaparece de la vista, es como si se fuera moviendo hacia la derecha y acaba desapareciendo. He reinstalado eclipse y el error persiste.
El sistema operativo es 6.8.0-48-generic - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS y el IDE eclipse Java es Version: 2024-09 (4.33.0) Build id: 20240905-0614




Puedes compartir una imagen del problema ?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

He agregado 3 imagenes porque desaparece en un segundo, gracias!

Arriba a la derecha, hay un boton para seleccionar las vistas y reestablecerlas, debería aparecer algo si haces click ahi.
